# Angular - how to reuse a standard data array

Tags: angular, angular-arrays

I am using a Indian states data array like the below in various components of my Angular project.

I know one way is to add it as a collection in backend database. But I would not like to make an API call to get the state names every time a dropdown needs it.

What is the best way to define it in ONE place within angular instead of defining this constant separately in each component.

```
const States = [
 { name:"Assam",  code:"18",  tin:"AS" },
  { name:"Bihar",  code:"10",  tin:"BH" },
  { name:"Chandigarh",  code:"04",  tin:"CH" },
....
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a file, `constArrays.ts` somewhere near the root of your application. You can then `export` the constant value like so:

```js
// constArrays.ts

export const States = [
 { name:"Assam",  code:"18",  tin:"AS" },
  { name:"Bihar",  code:"10",  tin:"BH" },
  { name:"Chandigarh",  code:"04",  tin:"CH" },
....
]
```

You can then import and use this in any other file like this:

```js
import * as constArrays from 'path/to/file/constArrays';
let states = constArrays.States;
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the best practice would be to create a [service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) - e.g. StatesService that would be  provided either in a module or a root of the application depending on the needs.
I would add a getStates() method that would return [observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables) of the states.

This way, in case your architecture ever changes, you're prepared that your data CAN be returned asynchronously from external source and all your code would still be valid.

A sample implementation:

```
export class State {
  name: string;
  code: string;
  tin: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StatesService {
    private states: State[] = [
    { name:"Assam",  code:"18",  tin:"AS" },
     { name:"Bihar",  code:"10",  tin:"BH" },
     { name:"Chandigarh",  code:"04",  tin:"CH" },
   ];

   getStates(): Observable<State[]> {
     return of(this.states);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Although I have marked the below answer as solution. I am going to try your answer too and also upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very easy to use and maintain with a configuration file.

states.config.json

```
[
  { "name":"Assam",  "code":"18",  "tin":"AS" },
  { "name":"Bihar",  "code":"10",  "tin":"BH" },
  { "name":"Chandigarh",  "code":"04",  "tin":"CH" }
]
```

then import it when need

```
import states from 'src/assets/states.config.json';
```